# Implementing a customizable Lexer class in Python

Tags: python, parsing, lexical-analysis

I want to implement a customizable and extendable lexer-class.

**My idea**

2 different types of *handlers*:

1. Character-set handlers
2. Function handlers

When a character is read, it is pushed through all handlers being registered to the lexer. As soon as a handler matches and returns a valid *Token*, it is returned. When no handler matches the character, a *worst-case* function is called, and if that doesn't return a valid *Token*, the next character is read and it goes on recursively.

A *character-set handler* consists of a string and a function taking three arguments. The string represents a set of characters that will cause to invoke the function when the currently parsed character is contained in that string. The function may return *None* when it is not able to create a token of the following characters. The function *must* push all characters back being read in order to create a *Token* if they could not be handled. Characters that were pushed back to the scanner will be returned on the next time `scanner.read_next_char()` is called, this enables to read the input' byte-stream like the function hasn't ever touched the scanner.

A *function handler* is a function taking three arguments that returns a valid *Token* or *None* if it could not create a valid *Token* with the characters following the character that invoked the handler, just like the functions being associated with a *character-set* above.

The *worst-case* function is called when no handler could create a valid *Token* from the current and it's following characters and follows the above described pattern.

Every handler takes three arguments, the *lexer* itself, the *scanner* used by the lexer (in order to read following characters) and the current character that actually invoked the handler.

The Lexer itself and the handlers are separated.

```
class LexingRules(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.charset_handlers  = []
        self.function_handlers = []
        self.worst_case        = None

    # convenient methods for adding handlers

class Lexer(object):

    def __init__(self, scanner, rules):
        self.scanner = scanner
        self.rules   = rules
        self.current_token = None
        self.read_next_token()

    def read_next_token(self):
        current_char = self.scanner.current_char

        for charset, handler in self.rules.charset_handlers:
            if current_char in charset:
                token = handler(self, self.scanner, current_char)
                if isinstance(token, Token):
                    self.current_token = token
                    return token
        for function in self.rules.function_handlers:
            token = function(self, self.scanner, current_char)
            if isinstance(token, Token):
                self.current_token = token
                return token
        if self.rules.worst_case:
            token = self.rules.worst_case(self, self.scanner, current_char)
            if isinstance(token, Token):
                self.current_token = token
                return token

        self.scanner.read()
        return self.read_next_token()
```

**A possible LexingRules subclass**

```
import string
class MyLexingRules(LexingRules):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLexingRules, self).__init__()
        self.charset_handlers.append(string.ascii_letters, self.handle_letters)

    def handle_letters(self, lexer, scanner, char):
        tkn = ''
        while scanner.current_char in string.ascii_letters:
            tkn += scanner.current_char
            scanner.read()
        return Token(tkn, TOKEN_ID_IDENTIFIER)
```

**The Aim**

*Separation of basic Lexer-implementation and hard-coded Lexing operations.*

I'm currently at the beginning of a project of my own. I want to create an extendable compiled/translated language. Syntax and statement-extension etc. should be possible to create.

**The Question**

What do you think about the design of the lexer, do you have something to complain about, or an idea of how to improve it, adding more functionality?

Comment: That seems like massive overengineering... what are you trying to lex?

Comment: Just added a small *edit*, "Separation of basic Lexer-implementation and hard-coded Lexing operations.". Language-extensions for "my new language" should be able not only to create new statements, even implementing new type of tokens, therefore syntax that will be parsed and converted to an AST by the extensions.

Comment: @delnan forgot that @ stuff..

Comment: @NiklasR: (1) Never put critical facts in comments.  Your "Aim" should probably be first, not last.  You can then remove the two useless comments, since they're now prominently placed  in your question.  (2) Which of the existing Python lexers are you familiar with?  You should reference them in your question.  `ply` is quite good and it's not clear how this can possibly improve on `ply`.